# Azure DevOps Classic Pipeline no branch filter

Tags: azure-devops

I have an Azure DevOps classic (non-YAML) build pipeline. I want the build to be triggered by a change on any branch. When I have no branch filters under Triggers -> Continuous Integration it tells me "You must add at least one branch filter".

The best I have come up with is to create a dummy branch (e.g. "DummyBranch") and then have a filter that is Excludes "DummyBranch" but this feels really hacky. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  wildcard characters in your branch specification. Please type "*" and press Enter. Here is my sample and this build will be triggered by a change on any branch:
[image]